# Cloud SQL resize would make me lose data?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We currently have a database hosted in **Google Cloud SQL**. We are paying almost 100$ but we use less than 5% of our size. Our configs are:

- **Version:** MySQL 8.0
- **Machine Type:** *High Memory* 4 vCPU, 26 GB
- **Storage Type:** SSD
- **Storage capacity:** 100GB

I was thinking of switching to **Machine Type High Memory** to **Lightweight**.

Would this delete my current database data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale up and down the memory and te CPU without data loss. Your database will be unavailable (you need to stop and to start it again with the new machine type configuration). Don't be afraid, you can do this

At, the opposite, you can scale up but not to scale down the storage capacity. If you want to achieve that, you need to export the data outside of your database, to delete the current Cloud SQL instance and to create a new one with a smallest disk. And then to reimport the data.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I resized it and everything's good :)